Collision with Inflated Bubbles: Error in Folds
I'm new to Blender and I wanted to ask if you have any tips to avoid the issue of collision with the folds of rubber balls. When I see it, strange pixels form and the fold isn't smooth. What do you think could be causing it?


Any information for me would be extremely useful for the study I'm doing. Thank you

Have you considered a fake collision object, slightly larger than the hero phone, in the right dimensions to be convincing to the camera.. to soak up the (expectable) error in collision  approximation?

You're thinking that the error depends on how the iPhone model is made. I replace it with a same shape. Thanks
